# Azure DevOps Use a Variable as a Condition between Deployment Stages

Tags: azure, yaml, terraform, azure-pipelines

I currently build all our Azure Infrastructure using Terraform via Azure DevOps Pipelines.  This has been working well and we have a standard pipeline which calls two templates

- Plan Stage

  - Deployment Job
  - Planning Template
  - Runs Every Time
- Apply Stage

  - Deployment Job
  - Apply Template
  - Runs with manual approval check

Now this works fine, but what I want to do is only have the apply step run if there are changes to make.  I have found other articles on how to get a variable set in the plan stage which I can do and it works fine.

I can call this same variable in the next step

```
  variables:
    varFromPlanStage: $[stageDependencies.Plan.planning_stage.outputs['planning_stage.terraformPlanResult.terraformChanges']]
  steps:
    - script: echo $(varFromPlanStage)
```

But the problem comes in when I try and use this same variable in a condition.
I found that the way you all it is different, needing a dependency instead of stagedependancy, but no matter what I try I can't get it to work.

The pipeline looks like this.

```
stages:
- stage: 'Plan'
  displayName: 'Planning'
  jobs:
  - deployment: planning_stage
    displayName: 'Planning Changes'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-20.04'
    environment: 'planning'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: /Pipelines/10-TEST-terraform-planning-template.yml  # Run the Planning Template
            parameters:
                terraform_version: ${{ parameters.terraform_version }}
                terraform_backend_service_arm: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_service_arm }}
                terraform_backend_resource_group: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_resource_group }}
                terraform_backend_storage_account: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_storage_account }}
                terraform_backend_storage_container: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_storage_container }}
                terraform_state_key: ${{ parameters.terraform_state_key }}
                git_working_directory: ${{ parameters.git_working_directory }}

# This is the Build Stage - Only do this when on the master branch (which is via a PR)

- stage: 'Apply'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Plan.planning_stage.outputs['planning_stage.terraformPlanResult.terraformChanges'], 'true'))
  variables:
    varFromPlanStage: $[stageDependencies.Plan.planning_stage.outputs['planning_stage.terraformPlanResult.terraformChanges']]
  displayName: 'Applying Changes'
  jobs:
  - deployment: applying_stage
    displayName: 'Lets Build'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-20.04'
    environment: 'building'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo $(varFromPlanStage) # Just a test
            - template: /Pipelines/20-TEST-terraform-apply-template.yml  # Run the Apply Template
              parameters:
                  terraform_version: ${{ parameters.terraform_version }}
                  terraform_backend_service_arm: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_service_arm }}
                  terraform_backend_resource_group: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_resource_group }}
                  terraform_backend_storage_account: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_storage_account }}
                  terraform_backend_storage_container: ${{ parameters.terraform_backend_storage_container }}
                  terraform_state_key: ${{ parameters.terraform_state_key }}
                  git_working_directory: ${{ parameters.git_working_directory }}
```

And the part of the Planning Template that exports the variable is called **terraformPlanResult** with the var being **terraformChanges**

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, and why I can't call the variable as a condition but I can as part of the steps?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work differently depending on whether you're setting the variable in a 'deployment' job, or a 'job' job. After some trial, error and googling I managed to get working for both. Examples below :-)

- Example passing variables from a 'deployment' job.

```
# Example passing variables from a 'deployment' job.
stages:

  # Create some variables to pass to next stage.
 - stage: 'A'
    jobs:
    - deployment: 'A1'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      environment: 'test'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            # Create a variable.
            - task: PowerShell@2
              name: foo
              displayName: 'Create a variable.'
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bar;isOutput=true]apple"
            # Check variable.
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'Check a variable.'
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
              env:
                MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(foo.bar)

  # Confirm condition works & variables are available for use.
 - stage: 'B'
    dependsOn:
    - 'A'
    variables:
      - name: varFromStageA
        # stageDependencies.stageName.deploymentName.outputs['deploymentName.stepName.variableName']
        value: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['A1.foo.bar'] ]
    # dependencies.stageName.outputs['deploymentName.deploymentName.stepName.variableName']
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.outputs['A1.A1.foo.bar'], 'apple'))
    jobs:
    - job: 'B1'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      steps:
      # Confirm variable has been passed between stages.
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Confirm var passed between stages'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
        env:
          MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(varFromStageA)
```

- Example passing variables from a 'job' job.

```
# Example passing variables from a 'job' job.
stages:

  # Create some variables to pass to next stage.
  - stage: 'A'
    jobs:
    - job: 'A1'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      steps:
      # Create a variable.
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: foo
        displayName: 'Create a variable.'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bar;isOutput=true]apple"
      # Check variable.
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Check a variable.'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
        env:
          MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(foo.bar)

  # Confirm condition works & variables are available for use.
  - stage: 'B'
    dependsOn:
    - 'A'
    variables:
      - name: varFromStageA
        # stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']
        value: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['foo.bar'] ]
    # dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.outputs['A1.foo.bar'], 'apple'))
    jobs:
    - job: 'B1'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      steps:
      # Confirm variable has been passed between stages.
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Confirm var passed between stages'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
        env:
          MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(varFromStageA)
```

Comment: Excellent!  This has solved it for me, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, this works! The key really is to duplicate the name of the deployment job when accessing the outputs (which seems like a bug tbh):
dependencies.A.outputs['A1.A1.foo.bar']

Answer (score 0):

What's working for me (by many trials and errors) is the format:

`dependencies.stage_name.outputs['job_name.step_name.variable_name']`

In your case, this would be:

`dependencies.Plan.outputs['planning_stage.terraformPlanResult.terraformChanges']`

If that doesn't work, the only unusual thing is that your `planning_stage` is a deployment. You might try and change it to a regular job.

Here's a [pipeline that tests various ways of referencing outputs in conditions](https://dev.azure.com/heavymetaldev/heavymetaldev/_build/results?buildId=132&view=results).

Comment: Thanks.  The reason for the deployment and not a regular job is that I have manual approvals set on this so it can't go into the apply stage if there are changes without manual approval.   I tried to do it with a regular job but couldn't get it to work but a deployment did.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like an issue on Azure Devops (later O will preapre minimial working example and create a bug for this). Because the same syntax works correctly for regular jobs but not for deployment. Also you can use condition like   `condition: in(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')` but not outputs. And according to this

```json
"dependencies": {
  "<STAGE_NAME>" : {
    "result": "Succeeded|SucceededWithIssues|Skipped|Failed|Canceled",
    "outputs": {
        "jobName.stepName.variableName": "value"
    }
  },
  "...": {
    // another stage
  }
}
```

it is correct syntax.

I also checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables) but using life cycle hook instead of job name doesn't helped me.

What is trange that you can use output variables in job condition if ther are in the same stage.

[Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Outputs-variable-set-in-deployment-jobs/1454297?space=21&q=Outputs+variable+set+in+deployment+jobs+are+not+aviable+in+stage+conditions) is link to the issue.